# Codeigniter. Automatic username check using jquery. Conceptual confusion

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, conceptual

I have recently started using CodeIgniter, and I can see its benefits.

I am however seemingly encountering a few conceptual problems which are confusing me.

For some things CodeIgniter is making relatively simple things ridiculously hard.

Take for example a registration form whereby on inputting a username it checks its availability, and automatically informs you..

My approach to this is as follows.

A controller 'Account' with a function 'register' which loads a view 'register_form' which has jquery included, and my custom javascript.

My custom javascript passes the username typed in to a function called 'username_check' in the 'Account' controller which passes the value to the function 'username_check' within my model 'user_model' which returns a count of rows with that username which is then passed to a view which outputs 'taken' or 'available' dependent on the count. It is then this response view which is placed into a div by the javascript.

Now... I struggled to write that down.. it baffles me just reading it, And conceptually it takes me about 10 minutes every time i want to add something just to find what i should be adding it to..

Can someone please tell me I have missed the point, and tell me how to implement this functionality.. correctly..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're new to the MVC concept. When I started using CI I designed a basic [illustration](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/2424/mvcm.jpg) that helped me understand MVC. After practice CI will make a lot of sense, namely the MVC pattern.

Your approach is correct. For me it makes sense to write code in the order that a user interacts with your website. Start with the view, then controller, and lastly model.

I recommend that you read the documentation thoroughly and just practice. Afterwards post your code.

Comment: I like your second paragraph, I usually do that kind of "top-down" design as well - figure out what the users need, build the interface, then write what I need to make it happen, pushing as much business logic to the model layer as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your thinking is quite correct. Model should take care of data (in your case it queries the db) while view should handle displaying of the data in whatever form it is.

Comment: Well.. I kinda know it is correct CI logic, but it is so so complicated.

I was thinking.. for things like this should i just have a stand alone script independent of codeigniter for example?

Comment: @Thomas: Well i guess your Opinion is your opinion, but i wouldnt call that complicated its pretty simple MVC flow. I also wouldnt recommend having a standalone script. I wouldnt return a full view though id jsut return JSON directly from the controller sying whether or not the login exists then hide show a messege that was actually already present in the view from the initial request for the form. Assuming one can do that in CI.